# When NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate change type happens?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I wonder when `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` change type in `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` method is passed?

I've created `NSFetchedResultsController` with non-nil `sectionNameKeyPath` and fetch request that have `sortDescriptor`. Added few objects that matched fetched request predicate. Then I've tried both changing of sort property and `sectionNameKeyPath` property of one of that objects. Actually it worked fine: changed object moved around a tableView, BUT every time I've received  `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` change type! Changing of other props (not used for sorting or sections) of that object did not trigger `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` at all!

The reason why I'm interested in `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` is that I want `NSFetchedResultsController` to notify me when certain property of already fetched object changes in bounds matching `NSFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate`. For example, predicate matches object of certain entity with `prop == 1 OR prop == 2`. But I also want to be notified when one of such matched objects changes it's `prop` value from 1 to 2.

Just don't want to create two `NSFetchedResultsController`s since I believe there is a more elegant way. + `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` change type is the only one mystery still undiscovered for me about `NSFetchedResultsController` - never caught it.

Answer (score 1):

I receive this `type` value when I create a second managed object context, using the same persistent store, edit the value of an object, and then save the context down into the persistent store.

(If I change the name that it's sorted on, I get the `ChangeMove` value, as you mention.)

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

 …
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
          [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] 
                      inTable:tableView 
                  atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;
 …
```

`anObject` = `NSManagedObject` subclass of relevant changed object

`indexPath` = relevant index

`newIndexPath` = `nil`

(the reason i create a second context is for a variety of use cases; one case: "new foo object", user fiddles creating a variety of owned relationships, then hits cancel, i just trash the context, no undo management needed)

Comment: Does NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate fire when entities *related* to entities managed by an NSFetchedResultsController change? For example, let's say I'm creating TVCs that display a parent entity, with a count of child entities based on a "to many" relationship. What happens if the number of child entities changes? Is that something I would have to handle on my own? (I'm guessing yes.)

Comment: from the docs: 
Changes are reported with the following heuristics:

On add and remove operations, only the added/removed object is reported.
It’s assumed that all objects that come after the affected object are also moved, but these moves are not reported. 

…